# JavaFX Scene Builder: pointer cursor onMouseOver

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

Is it possible to set the mouse cursor to become a pointer (hand) when hovering a Node width JavaFX Scene Builder? How?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can add the following `Style` to the Node in question:

```
-fx-cursor: hand;
```

For additional options, check out the [JavaFX CSS Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#Nodes)

Comment: Why haven't I found that myself? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

for the new one you can use this in your css file

```
.glyph-icon{
    -fx-fill: White;
}
.glyph-icon:hover{
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-fill: black;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Version of Gluon Scene Builder (v11+), this feature is available under the `Properties > Cursor` with a few other options as well.

The good thing about this feature is that **the cursor is updated while you view the options**, i.e how will setting that property look like as shown in the below GIF.

[image]